# Magento: not shipped item collection

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I would like to get all items that has not been shipped for a given order.

Suppose  that I have a  partial shipped order I would like to retrieve all items that are pending to be shipped.

Something like:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('...')->getCollection()
                     ->Add...()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$orderId = 382;

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
// OR if you load the order with increment id ...
// $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId); 
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();

foreach ($orderItems as $item) {

    $qtyToBeShipped = $item->getQtyOrdered() - $item->getQtyShipped();

    if ($qtyToBeShipped)
        echo $item->getId() . ' - ' . $qtyToBeShipped . '</br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @mpaepper for hint.

Comment: Great, that looks even better :)

Comment: I had to use $_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId); instead of $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

Comment: thx, yes it depends if you use the `increment_id` or the `order_id` to load the order ... I have added it as a comment to the code.

Answer (score 3):

To get all items of the order, use the item collection:

```
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
```

And then use the shipment model to get all the items of the order:

```
   $shippedItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')
    ->setOrder($order)->getItemsCollection();
```

Edit2: Turns out that setting the order on the shipment does not work to get the items collection, since there can be several shipments for an order. Use the code snippet provided below, instead.

Edit: I forgot that there could be several shipments, so here is the full working code to get all Ids of the order items and all Ids of the shipped ones:

```
$orderId = 15;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection();
$allOrderItemIds = $orderItems->getAllIds();
$shipments = $order->getShipmentsCollection();
$shippedItemIds = array();
foreach ($shipments as $shipment) {
        $shippedItems = $shipment->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($shippedItems as $item) {
                $shippedItemIds[] = $item->getOrderItemId();
        }
}
var_dump($allOrderItemIds);
var_dump($shippedItemIds);
```

Comment: @Francesco Edited this with a working code example I just tested, you have to adjust the $orderId of course.

Comment: @Francesco I believe there is no better way to do this, unfortunately. This is because the order has no idea about shipped items, but only its shipment does. The only other possibility is to build a custom SQL query which joins the tables together, i.e. sales_flat_order, sales_flat_shipment and sales_flat_shipment_item

Comment: check my answer ... order knows everything about its items :)